# Could an Application restriction on a Firebase auto generated API key result in an App break?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

When we create a new project in Firebase and add iOS or Android app to it Firebase will automatically create API keys in Google Cloud.

Example: Android key (auto created by Firebase)

As per documentation it's not mandatory to secure those keys if we have proper security rules at the backend(Firestore/Cloud Storage). Of course an attacker can make a brute force attack using the authentication endpoints which can be mitigated by putting thresholds on authentication limits.

My question is would it cause a break in the app functionality or unexpected behaviour if an auto created API key is secured with a bundle id or SHA-1 key?

Answer (score 0):

For sure.  [Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys) notes the following:

> If an API key is currently in use by a production app, you need to be cautious about adding restrictions to that API key. You should test your restrictions in a testing app and with a test API key before adding any restrictions to your production API key.

Comment: is there a list of recommended minimum restrictions? which APIs are mandatory?